# Is a connected set always an uncountably infinite set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

I'm trying to understand the concept of a connected set. The classic example which is presented is that of $\Bbb R$ or any interval of $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology.
Moreover, I heard that to a certain extent connected sets can be considered opposite to discrete sets. They are sometimes indicated as representing the idea of a continuum. So, intuitively, shouldn't they always be uncountable sets?

Comment: It's plainly false that every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is connected. The connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are the empty set, the singletons and all intervals. But $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ is obviously disconnected.

Comment: @egreg You're right. I meant any interval :)

Comment: @GabrieleScarlatti You might want to edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Luke I"ve edited it :)

Answer (score 22):

First of all, $\emptyset$ is connected. And so is every singleton.

On the other hand, it is true that every connected *metric* space with more than one point is uncountable. But there are countable connected *topological* spaces.

Comment: I've heard some argue that the empty set is not connected, in a similar sense to 1 not being a prime number. See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/too+simple+to+be+simple for related thoughts.

Comment: @BenMillwood, to me, the empty set is probably connected, but not $0$-connected (because $0$-connected implies $(-1)$-connected, and the latter is equivalent to being non-empty).

Answer (score 12):

Consider the space $X  = \{a, b\}$ equipped with the trivial topology (i.e. the only open sets are $X$ and $\varnothing$). Then, the space is connected, but there are only a finite number of points in this example.

Comment: Even cooler is the [pseudocircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocircle). It's the smallest multiconnected space.

Answer (score 8):

Well, there's the empty set, as others have noted. Also, every singleton is connected. But you can say a bit more if you assume some separation.

- Any finite $T_1$ space is discrete, so it is connected if and only if it has only one point, so if you assume $T_1$, there are no nontrivial connected *finite* sets or spaces.
- There are also connected $T_0$ spaces of any size you want (including any finite): if you take a nonempty set $X$ and fix $x\in X$, then if you declare open sets to be exactly those containing $x$, then the resulting topology is $T_0$ and connected (all points except for $x$ are closed).
- On any infinite set (possibly countable), the cofinite topology is $T_1$ and connected.
- There are [connected countably infinite Hausdorff spaces.](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Connected%2BCountable%2B%24T_2%24) (and even $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$-spaces).
- A connected $T_4$ space with more than one point is necessarily uncountable. This follows easily from Urysohn's lemma (in fact, it follows that a nontrivial connected $T_4$ space has at least the cardinality of the continuum).
- One can show that a countable $T_3$ space is $T_4$, so by the preceding point, a connected $T_3$ space cannot be countably infinite.

Incidentally, in topology, a continuum is a kind of connected set (namely one which is compact Hausdorff, or even metrisable, depending on the author).